# Notepad++ Regex Get all FULL links that begins with a string in a HTML

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

guys...

I have a big HTML, and i want to take all links that start with

"https://exampledomain.com/category/" and delete the rest, the HTML have links like "https://exampledomain.com/edit/..."  "https://exampledomain.com/view/...", have tags, texts, and i want to delete all but no "https://exampledomain.com/category/.../"[image]

the final result must be like this:

```
https://www.exampledomain/category/presents/
https://www.exampledomain/category/books/
https://www.exampledomain/category/clothes/
https://www.exampledomain/category/bags/
```

Any ideas?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Quick way: replace `a href="` with a new line then sort the lines (TextFX)

Comment: Can you post a text example? Transcribing that image will be a hassle.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your idea saved me! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alex proposed, i've used search and replace to sepparate the links alone in a line (using extended \n)...

**Search**: `(https://www.exampledomain/category/[^"]*)` 
To match all link until (") (end of href="url")
 
**Replace with**: `\n\n\1\n\n`

When its done, i've used notepad++ " CTFL + F > Mark " to select all lines that contains

```
https://www.exampledomain/category/
```

then, removed no marked lines... Using Menu > search > markers > remove no selected lines...

Thanks! :D

Comment: How do you remove the trailing cruft ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

**Wrap around:**: yes
**Find:** `.*?"(https://www.exampledomain/category/.*?)"|.*`
**Replace:** `\1\n`
**Regular expression:** yes
**`.` matches newline:** yes

Click **Replace All**

Comment: Could you let me know whether this worked for you?